# How to correctly scope public method in Rails using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to make sure this method only allows editing of data that is appropriate for the current account. I am running Rails 3.12, using acts_as_tenant for managing accounts, and devise for user authentication.

When I try to access /dataload_mailchimp/edit I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `api_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000006d02590>):
2013-09-27T17:12:23.947590+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/dataload_mailchimps_controller.rb:32:in `edit'
```

As I understand the error an api_key is not found. However, I am logged in as a user for account_id = 3 and there is a valid api_key for that account_id in the dataload_mailchimps table.

I am trying to better understand how I scope this method correctly so the correct record from dataload_mailchimps is returned?

Thanks for any help or advice.

my controller:

```
class DataloadMailchimpsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def edit
    @dataload = DataloadMailchimp.where( account_id: current_user.account )
    unless @dataload
      redirect_to new_dataload_mailchimp_path
    else
      gibbon = Gibbon.new(@dataload.api_key)
      @lists = []
      gibbon.lists['data'].each do |list|
        @lists << MailchimpList.find_or_create_by_list_id(:list_id => list['id'], :name => list['name'])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

from the dataload_mailchimps table:

```
id      api_key       account_id
4       6a3           3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `@dataload` instance variable holds an `ActiveRecord::Relation` type, where you actually want it to hold a `DataloadMailchimp` object. Try the following lookup instead:

```
@dataload = DataloadMailchimp.find_by_account_id(current_user.account.id)
```

As an FYI, the `where()` method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object holding a collection of *all* class objects that match the conditions. In contrast, `find_by_` returns the *first instance* of a class object that matches the conditions.